# How to parse complex key-value pairs from an input file (.properties or .json) into a batch script?

Tags: java, json, maven, batch-file, tomcat

I am currently working on a batch script that will allow me to automatically delete files based on the file's age. I have already figured out the script command that i'll need to implement into my batch script as follows:

**FORFILES /P "C:\Path\" /M *.txt* /S /D -7 /C "cmd /c del @path"**

The files I want to delete are Maven SNAPSHOTS that are deeply embedded in their own folder paths, identifiable by the dependency's groupID, artifactID, and version#. If you don't know what I mean by that, here is an example:

NOTE: The root folder that holds all my dependencies is C:\Users\
 {UserName}.m2\repository...

1. groupID: org.apache.tomcat
2. artifactID: tomcat-catalina

-- So within ".m2\repository", there will be a folder titled "org" (i think of this as my groupID parent folder), and within that folder are sub-directories, "apache" and "tomcat" that correspond to the rest of the groupID. In the folder ".m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat", it holds a folder that corresponds to the artifactID, titled "tomcat-catalina".

What I want to be able to do is list one (or more) groupID/artifactID pairs into an input file. From there, my batch script will fetch the groupID/artifactID data from the input file, break down the data into their own parameters based on their folder path (breaking down groupID is my main confusion), and have the delete script command *change* depending on the groupID/artifactID that is set in the input file.

NOTE: I've looked at working w/ different input file formats, but mainly these three: *.properties, .json, .yaml*. What would be the most efficient format to use for this task?

Based on this information, does anyone know how I would be able to accomplish this? Thanks for reading or answering!

Comment: I'm relatively new to scripting, but I can pickup/learn pretty easily if i'm directed in the right path.

I also thought about including different function options that can be enabled through my input file. So if I wanted to enable a *backup* function that is executed before *delete* in my script, then all the user would have to do is set the "backupOption" value as 1. And if they wanted to disable the *backup* function, then they can set the value as 0; OR, if they left that value as blank, e.g. "backupOption: ", then the batch file would automatically have the function disabled.

Comment: Simply delete the `$home/.m2/repository` ? What is the real problem here? Why making is so complicated ?